# how to map comments in drupal migrate module

Tags: migrations

So im migrating comments from a different database to Drupal 7 but i cant understand why this wont work. Im successful with migrating nodes, i only mapped the node fields and somehow its node_revision seemed to have automatically updated too.

But in comments it doesnt work, i know to add a comment these tables are affected in drupal:

1. comment
2. field_data_comment_body
3. field_revision_comment_body

am i missing some mapping here in my code?

```
$this->addFieldMapping('cid', 'id');
    $this->addFieldMapping('is_new')->defaultValue(TRUE); // i dont know what this thing does


    $this->addFieldMapping('nid', 'mainthread');
    $this->addFieldMapping('pid', 'parent')
         ->sourceMigration('ForumComment')
         ->description('Parent comment.');
    $this->addFieldMapping('comment_body', 'body');
    $this->addFieldMapping('subject', 'subject');
    $this->addFieldMapping('hostname', 'host');
    $this->addFieldMapping('created', 'date');
    $this->addFieldMapping('changed', 'last');
    $this->addFieldMapping('name', 'author');
    $this->addFieldMapping('status')
         ->defaultValue(COMMENT_PUBLISHED);
    $this->addFieldMapping('comment_body:format')
        ->defaultValue('full_html');

    /*$this->addFieldMapping('uid', 'accountid')
         ->sourceMigration('WineUser')
         ->defaultValue(1); */


    //optional
    //$this->addFieldMapping('tid', 'category_id');
    //$this->addFieldMapping('comment_count', 'hits');

    // Unmapped destination fields
    $this->addUnmigratedDestinations(array('uid', 'thread', 'mail', 'homepage', 'language', 'comment_body:language'));

      $this->addUnmigratedSources(array('category_id'));
```

and is my destination correct? here it is:

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationComment('comment');
```

based on my code only the comment table is mapped, i just assumed that the body and its revision will automatically map too like in my migration of nodes.

Help please

Answer (score 1):

I got it, you need to add another class for the mapping of the body of the comment

and the destination should be 'comment_node_forum'

Comment: do you mind showing code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow a format here:

so instead of

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationComment('comment');
```

It should be

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationComment('comment_node_article');
```

Where comment_node_'nodetype' is a format and above the node type that I have used is "article".